# How can I limit a response to a php filter to only one?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I created a filter in php for wordpress that displays a special message when a product with a certain shipping class is in the cart. The special message shows up multiple times, for however many products of that class are in the cart. How can I limit the output to only one? Here's the code:

```html
 add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'allclean_add_checkout_content', 12 );
function allclean_add_checkout_content() {
    // set your special category name, slug or ID here:
    $shippingclass =  array( 'cut' );
    $bool = false;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
 $shipping_class = get_the_terms( $values['variation_id'], 'product_shipping_class' );

        if ( isset( $shipping_class[0]->slug ) && in_array( $shipping_class[0]->slug, $shippingclass ) ) {
            $bool = true;
    }
    // If the special cat is detected in one items of the cart
    // It displays the message
    if ($bool)
        echo '<div class="example1"><h3>Items in your cart can be cut to save on shipping. List which items you want cut in your order notes.</h3></div>';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're echoing it within the `foreach` loop. Simply move it outside. Also, after the first instance is found, there is no need to continue the loop, therefore break it with `break` after you set `$bool` to `true`

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'allclean_add_checkout_content', 12);

function allclean_add_checkout_content()
{
    // set your special category name, slug or ID here:
    $shippingclass = array('cut');
    $bool = false;
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values)
    {
        $shipping_class = get_the_terms($values['variation_id'], 'product_shipping_class');

        if (isset($shipping_class[0]->slug) && in_array($shipping_class[0]->slug, $shippingclass))
        {
            $bool = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    // If the special cat is detected in one items of the cart
    // It displays the message
    if ($bool)
    {
        echo '<div class="example1"><h3>Items in your cart can be cut to save on shipping. List which items you want cut in your order notes.</h3></div>';
    }
}
```